# RxJava 2 force complete chain with infinite observable

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an observable chain that has infinite observable on the top and non infinite observables after it. Like this:

```
repo.infinitGetItems()
      .switchMap(items -> Observable
                          .just(items)
                          .flatMap(items -> repo.nonInfinitObs(items)));
```

What I want is to complete all chain when `repo.nonInfinitObs` sends `onComplete` event. Now it's not completing because `repo.infinitGetItems()` is still alive.

Could I do something like force complete for the whole chain in rxJava2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the main sequence via `takeUntil` and some flow-external means:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> stop = PublishSubject.create();

repo.infinitGetItems()
  .takeUntil(stop)
  .switchMap(items -> repo.nonInfinitObs(items)
                      .doOnComplete(() -> stop.onComplete())
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a try.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you for time and answer :)